# Mapcan's behavior on atoms

Tags: common-lisp, map-function

I am pretty much of a newbie to common-lisp and only use it for fun. But I assume to know the difference between mapper and mapcan, as the documentation in the hyperspec and other places is pretty clear.

But what happens if the function mapcan calls on the list elements evaluates to an atom instead of a list? As mapcan uses nconc to append lists, I had expected that there would be an error if there is no list.

But if I try

```
(mapcan (lambda (x) (+ 2 x)) '(1 2 3 4))
```

it evaluates to '6' in sbcl and clisp. (There might not be a practical need for this example; I am just curious) I see the point that returning a value might be nicer than a simpler error but could find anything about mapcan returning the last value if there are no lists to nconc.

Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: LispWorks and GCL signal an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `mapcan`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) `(mapcan (lambda (x) (+ 2 x)) '(1 2 3 4))` Should do the same as `(apply #'nconc (mapcar (lambda (x) (+ 2 x)) '(1 2 3 4)))` and it signals an error the error `*** - NCONC: 5 is not a list`  in clisp.

The hyperspec only shows what `nconc` should be doing with proper lists and `nil` as the arguments before last. It does not have anything else described so what you are seeing is that `sbcl` and `clisp` perhaps share the algorithm from a lisp in public domain or that they have implemented it so similar they have the same implementation specific results.

You probably cannot assume other implementations will do the same so you should make sure the function passed to `mapcan` always return a fresh list or `nil` that can be `nconc`-ed within [the specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm#nconc).